# How to write curried polymorphic function & its higher kind in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, scala-3, higher-kinded-types, dotty, polymorphic-functions

In Scala 3, I'm able to write a poly-function of type 1:

```
  val y = [C <: Int] => (x: C) => x * 2
```

When I try to generalise it into type 2:

```
  val z = [C <: Int] => ([D <: Int] => (x: C, y: D) = x * y)
```

I got the following error:

```
DependentPoly.scala:19:37: Implementation restriction: polymorphic function literals must have a value parameter
```

So is this feature not implemented? Or I'm not writing it properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Implementation restriction: polymorphic function literals must have a value parameter` means that

```
val y = [C <: Int] => foo[C]
```

is illegal (for example for `def foo[C <: Int]: C => Int = _ * 2`) while

```
val y = [C <: Int] => (x: C) => x * 2
```

is legal.

Similarly,

```
val z = [C <: Int] => [D <: Int] => (x: C, y: D) => x * y
val z = [C <: Int] => [D <: Int] => (x: C) => (y: D) => x * y
```

are illegal while

```
val z = [C <: Int, D <: Int] => (x: C, y: D) => x * y
val z = [C <: Int, D <: Int] => (x: C) => (y: D) => x * y
val z = [C <: Int] => (x: C) => [D <: Int] => (y: D) => x * y
val z = [C <: Int] => (_: C) => [D <: Int] => (x: C, y: D) => x * y
val z = [C <: Int] => (_: C) => [D <: Int] => (x: C) => (y: D) => x * y
```

are legal.

This is because of

```
trait PolyFunction:
  def apply[A](x: A): B[A]
```

https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/new-types/polymorphic-function-types.html

https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/4672

Comment: In the very first example, `foo(_: C)` works instead of `foo[C]`, but I somehow don't see whether there are shorter ways to eta-expand it.

Comment: Wow, just wow ... Arrows everywhere

Comment: verified in Scala 3.2.1 !

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks. Yeah, `foo(_: C)` is a shorthand for `(x: C) => x * 2`. My point was that currently we can't omit `(x: C)` even if there is no value-level parameter in `foo` (for example if `foo` transforms types into values).

Comment: @AndreyTyukin For example `inline def foo[C <: Int]: C = constValue[C]` or `inline def foo[C <: Int]: C = summonInline[ValueOf[C]].value`